# spring or servlet request scope problem

Tags: java, web-services, spring, servlets, scope

I use java, spring-ws and have a web service.

Every time I run make a new request to my web service I want that everything resets and all variables are fresh and null. So I added "scope=request" to my web service's application-context.xml but I still have the variable values(even not static vars) kept from my previous request.

My web service(as a jar file) is being used as a plugin from another main web project. and I gave reference to my web service **from the main web project's web.xml** file like this;

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/resources/webservice/applicationContext-WebService.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Also in this web.xml I define another dispatcher servlet for the main project, is that possible that it creates 2 spring containers and they interfere?

this is how I define scope in the web service's appcontext.xml file:

```
<bean id="infService" class="com.ws.im.InfService" scope="request">
    <property name="webServiceConfiguration" ref="wsConfiguration" />

    <property name="properties">
        <bean class="com.ws.PropertyResource">
            <property name="resource" value="/WEB-INF/clientspecific/Inf.properties" />
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

So I guess everytime I run my main web project it loads once in the beginning my web service's app context.xml file and no matter I change its scope it does not work cause the main project defines the scope? Can I define the scope of a servlet above? or this idea is totally wrong and I did something wrong in my web service configuration xml's?

thanks

Comment: Can you please show where you added `scope=request` in `applicationContext-WebService.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have gone wrong somewhere else because your config looks fine.

Can you add some code into the constructor of `com.ws.im.InfService` :

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info(
    "Instantiated, identity [" + System.identityHashCode(this) +"]");
```

This should print a different identity string for each request, if the request scoping is working correctly.

**Edit:**

Needed to add `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` to bean definition

Comment: tnx, I tried what u said and it prints same string everytime, so scope does not work. what can I do?

Comment: Sorry I should have written `System.identityHashCode(this)` ... can you try that?

Comment: yeah I tried, scope does not work..and I noticed I have erros in console "No thread-bound request found" I added request listener to my web.xml but didnt fix the problem

Comment: Try adding `<aop:scoped-proxy />` in the infService definition

Comment: I always forget to add it too... See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection for a better explanation than I can give